# Getting Remote(client) Username in jsp page hosted via tomcat in Unix

Tags: jsp, unix, tomcat

Friends I am trying to get the remote user's windows id via jsp page to keep it. I am unable to get it.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking for NTLM or Kerberos servlet filter.